# Drawable rectangle solid with alpha

Tags: android, kotlin, drawable

I would like to know if its possible to use alpha in the shape instead of using #Hexacimal.

Currently the best way is to use `#(transparent code)(color hexa)`
But for dark theme reason, I would like to know if its possible to do something like

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="32dp" />
    <solid android:color="?attr/primary" android:alpha="0.24" />
</shape>
```

instead of

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="32dp" />
    <solid android:color="#3DFFFFFF"/>
</shape>
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

There is not another option besides the color hex.

Here are all of the options available for Shape drawables with Android: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape